# How to revise my app concept to provide a more robust user experience by including native iOS features and functionality?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, native

App Review:Rejected - Design 4.2.2

Message from Apple Review Team:

Please revise your app concept to provide a more robust user experience by including native iOS features and functionality.

What native features do iOS devices have, I really don't have a need for Health-kit, gyro-meter and camera.

I already have Offline data sync and Push notifications included, what else could I possibly use in the very limited iOS feature hut?

Comment: You're not going to get much help without describing what your app does. No one's going to tell you everything the phone does.

Answer (score 2):

Apple has made this rule around before 2 or more year ago. Actually this is because there was so much rush of the template kind of apps with less features & due to that the other quality Apps was getting less attention.

There is 2 possible ways to get out this situation :

1. You can explain apple review team by high lighting key features of your app & try to convince them that your app contains enough features to get approval. You can post message just below the rejection message by them.
2. If 1st option does not works & they are not convinced by the features than you must than add few more helpful features in the app & upload the new binary.

**Important note :**

- In case of adding new feature & submitting new binary don't forget to add comment on review notes that you have added few key features & app is now with full of features as per the apple rules.

Hope it will help you.